# as3 font embedding from parent to child swf

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a parent swf with fonts embedded in the library, which have export for actionscript set and a class name assigned. The patent swf loads a number of child swfs to which I'm trying to pass a textformat object using a desired font from the parents library. How can this be achieved. I have tried Font.registerFont(font class) and created a new instance of the font before setting the textformat, but this only works on machines with the font installed.

In the child swf, the textfield text is set, then the textfomat applied with setTextFormat();

Any pointers greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
import flash.text.*;
var font:Font1=new Font1();
var txt_fmt:TextFormat=new TextFormat();
txt_fmt.font=font.fontName;
txt_fmt.size=24
var txt:TextField=new TextField();
txt.autoSize=TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
txt.defaultTextFormat=txt_fmt;
txt.embedFonts=true
txt.text="sara"
txt.selectable=false
addChild(txt);
```

The code is from http://sara-intop.blogspot.com/2007/10/embedding-font-in-flash-cs3using-as3.html

Also you can find useful this: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/embedding_fonts.html

and this: http://learnola.com/2008/11/05/flash-tutorial-embed-fonts-in-actionscript-3/

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm looking to share a library font from a parent swf. The method above would require the font to be embedded in the child swf directly

Comment: When the parent finishes loading the child, can you pass an instance of the font class (in the above example Font1) to the loaded child? It's just an idea.

Comment: no use, I have a task simmilar to this. What i discovered is:
TextFileds created inside loaded swf can't get the parent swf font, there is none in font list (traced inside the chid swf)
Even registring it inside child font list didn't make it work.
Font list shows that there such font and it has needed characters, the textfield has needed format, but no text there :(

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out. I had to use the array returned by Font.enumerateFonts and declare a new Font class, then create a Textfomat object within the child swf and apply it to the textfield.

Comment: hey Geoff, can you please explain what you did? how did you declare a new Font class at runtime? thanx, Saar